# Python : extract substring from string

Tags: python, string, text-extraction

I would like to extract `'test'` from `'<AAA>test</AAA>'`. Here is my code. I'm sure it can be improved :

```
test = '<AAA>test</AAA>'

test = test.replace('</AAA>', '<AAA>')
test = test.split('<AAA>')
test = test[1]

print(test)
```

Any idea on how to write it in a lighter way ?

Many thanks...

Comment: Use an XML parser (unless you *really* only want to parse this one input).

Comment: How would you write it ?